# Display alter message in Webmethod

Tags: c#, asp.net, webmethod

```
[webMthod]

HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("<script>alert('your messsage')</script>");
```

Comment: Write(" <  script  > alert('your messsage') <  /script  > "); note the spaces, couldn't submit w/o them

Comment: Then, could you please give some more information about what you're trying to accomplsh?

Answer (score 0):

IF you doing ajax j query call to web method you can have alert in failure and success method, only return data from web method that you want to print.

```
<script type = "text/javascript">
    function ShowCurrentTime() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "WebForm3.aspx/GetCurrentTime",
            data: '{name: "' + $("#<%=txtUserName.ClientID%>")[0].value + '" }',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: OnSuccess,
            failure: function (response) {
                alert(response.d);
            }
        });
    }
    function OnSuccess(response) {
        alert(response.d);
    }
</script> 

  [System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
        public static string GetCurrentTime(string name)
        {

            return "messaage";
        }
```

Please let me know if you are doing anything else or you are doing something different than this.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean that you need a way to display an alternate message, besides the data that the method returns?

For this, i make use of a class, in which i embed the data i want to return. This way, all service methods return a common class, which has the message you want to pass, and the data that the caller actually needs.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

public class Service_Response
{
    public string Message { get; set; }
    public dynamic Data { get; set; }

    public Service_Response()
    {

    }

    public Service_Response(string msg)
    {
        this.Message = msg;
        this.Data = null;
    }

    public Service_Response(string msg, dynamic obj)
    {
        this.Message = msg;
        this.Data = obj;
    }

    public Service_Response(string msg, object obj, Type obj_type)
    {
        this.Message = msg;
        this.Data = Convert.ChangeType(obj, obj_type);
    }
}
```

To use it,

```
[WebMethod()]
public static Service_Response GetHelloWorld() {
      return new Service_Response("hello world", true);
}
//or
[WebMethod()]
public static Service_Response GetHelloWorld(int i) {
      return new Service_Response("hello world" + i);
}
//or
[WebMethod()]
public static Service_Response GetHelloWorld(string name) {
      var data = DateTime.Now;
      return new Service_Response("hello world from " + name, data);
}
```